# How could I select an item from list using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

there was a problem using selenium to select from list!!

I tried that code ...

```py
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.asiamiles.com/en/enrolment.html')
#title
title_list = driver.find_element_by_id('react-select-2--value')
title_list.send_keys('Mr')
```

the error message was that the item didn't found!!
`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`

how can i fix it?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't send_keys to that list, try to use

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.asiamiles.com/en/enrolment.html')
#title
title_list = driver.find_element_by_id('react-select-2--value')
title_list.click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "Mr")]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use `driver.find_elements_by_id()`. This returns a list which can then be filtered through.